# Should a class be able to catch an exception from a class that it doesn't know about?

Tags: oop

I wrote some code in an MVC Framework that looks something like:

```
class Controller_Test extends Controller
{
   public function action_index()
   {
      $obj = new MyObject();
      $errors = array();

      try
      {
         $results = $obj->doSomething();
      }
      catch(MyObject_Exception $e)
      {
         $e->getErrors();
      }
      catch(Exception $e)
      {
         $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
      }
}
```

My friend argues that the Controller should know nothing about MyObject, and therefore I should not catch MyObject_Exception.

He argues that the code should do something like this instead:

```
class Controller_Test extends Controller
{
   public function action_index()
   {
      $obj = new MyObject();
      $errors = array();

      if($obj->doSomething())
      {
         $results = $obj->getResults();
      }
      else
      {
         $errors = $obj->getErrors();
      }
}
```

I definitely understand his approach, but feel as though state management can lead to unintended side effects.

What is the right or preferred approach?

Edit: mistakenly put $obj->getErrors() in MyObject_Exception catch clause instead of $e->getErrors();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debate about exceptions vs. returned error codes is a long and bloody one.

His argument breaks down in that, by using a getErrors() function, you are *learning information about the object*. If that is your reason for using a boolean return to indicate success, then you are wrong. In order for the Controller to handle the error properly, it has to know about the object it was touching and what the specific error was. Was it a network error? Memory error? **It has to know in some way or another.**

I prefer the exception model because it's cleaner and allows me to handle more errors in a more controlled fashion. It also provides a clear cut way for the data relating to an exception to be passed.

However, I disagree with your use of a function like getErrors(). Any data pertaining to the exception that would help me handle it should be included with the exception. I should not have to go hunting into the object again to get information about what went wrong.

Did the network connection timeout? The exception should contain the host/port it tried to connect to, how long it waited, and any data from the lower networking levels.

Let's do this in example (in psuedo c#):

```
public class NetworkController {
    Socket MySocket = null;
    public void EstablishConnection() {
        try {
            this.MySocket = new Socket("1.1.1.1",90);
            this.MySocket.Open();

        } catch(SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            //Attempt a Single Reconnect
        }
        catch(InvalidHostNameException ex) {
            Log("InvalidHostname");
            Exit();
        }

    }
}
```

Using his method:

```
public class NetworkController {
    Socket MySocket = null;
    public Boolean EstablishConnection() {
        this.MySocket = new Socket("1.1.1.1",90);
        if(this.MySocket.Open()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            switch(this.MySocket.getError()) {
                case "timeout":
                    // Reattempt
                    break;
                case "badhost":
                    Log("InvalidHostname");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately, you need to know what happened to the object to know how to respond to it, and there is no sense in using some convoluted if statement set or switch-case to determine that. Use the exceptions and love them.

EDIT: I accidentally the last half of a sentence.

Comment: You are correct. in my pseudocode I mistakenly wrote $obj->getErrors() when I should have meant $e->getErrors() where the MyObject_Exception has data pertinent to the exception itself.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would say that what's important is whether the controller understands the *meaning* of the exception and can handle it properly. In many cases (if not most), the controller will not know how to properly handle the exception, and so should *not* catch and handle it.

On the other hand, the controller might reasonably be permitted to understand some specific exception like a "DatabaseUnavailableException", even if it has no idea how or why `MyObject` used a database. The controller might be permitted to retry the call to `MyObject` a certain number of times, all without knowing about how `MyObject` is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

First of all controller is not meant for handling the underlying exceptions thrown by classes.

Even if one occurs controller should halt saying something wrong at underlying error.

This way we make sure that controller does really and only do the job of flow control.

The other classes which give controller some output should be error free unless the error is very much controller specific.